# Why is this object treated differently when passed using pipeline vs named parameters?

Tags: .net, powershell, parameter-passing, powershell-cmdlet

I have been naïvely assuming that an object passed to a commandlet using PowerShell's pipeline parameter binding is treated the same as passing it using named parameters.  However, the following script seems to demonstrate there is a difference:

```
Function Process-xMsmqQueue{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter()]$obj,
    [Parameter(
        ValueFromPipeline=$True,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
    [System.Messaging.MessageQueue]$queue
    )
    Write-Host $obj
}

New-MsmqQueue 'xTest1' -ErrorAction Ignore
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Messaging') | Out-Null
New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue('.\private$\xTest1') -OutVariable q
$first = 'first'
$second = 'second'
$q | Process-xMsmqQueue -obj $first
Process-xMsmqQueue -queue $q -obj $second
```

I expected this script to print `first` and `second`.  Instead, it throws `ParameterArgumentTransformationError` on the last line:

[image]

The difference in treatment of the `$queue` parameter only seems to manifest for some object types.  For example, replacing `[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]` with `[System.String]` and passing a string to `$queue` yields no errors.

My Questions:

1. Why is the `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` object treated differently when passed using the pipeline versus named parameters?
2. Why isn't `System.String` affected by the difference?
3. How can I change this script to make passing by named parameter work for `-queue`?

Comment: Try writing the value of `$queue` when using a String type. My guess is that PowerShell does an implicit conversion that isn't really what you want, but it doesn't produce an error either.

Comment: Actually it looks like `-OutVariable` has something to do with it. It produces a variable with an ArrayList containing a single instance of `MessageQueue`. While `$q = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue('.\private$\xTest1')` produces just an object of type `MessageQueue`.

Comment: It seems like you're right.  And I bet the pipeline automatically iterates through ArrayList.

Comment: `$q | gm` indicates that `$q` is `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` type.  However, `$q.GetType()` returns `ArrayList`.  It looks like [Get-Member](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849928.aspx) reports on items in a collection piped to it, not the collection itself.

Answer (score 1):

As @mikez [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27474975/why-is-this-object-treated-differently-when-passed-using-pipeline-vs-named-param?noredirect=1#comment43384574_27474975) the answers to all three questions are obvious once you realize that `-OutVariable` produces a ArrayList of objects.  `-Outvariable` is suitable for further consumption by the pipeline and [seems to exist to facilitate inspection of objects passed through the pipeline](http://mcpmag.com/articles/2009/05/12/inspecting-the-pipelines-output.aspx).

### Question 1

> Why is the System.Messaging.MessageQueue object treated differently
>   when passed using the pipeline versus named parameters?

Consider the following line:

```
New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue('.\private$\xTest1') -OutVariable q
```

actually produces an object of type `System.Messaging.MessageQueue[]` (not `System.Messaging.MessageQueue`) which is an Arraylist of MessageQueues.

**Pipeline**

Consider this line:

```
$q | Process-xMsmqQueue -obj $first
```

As I understand it, Powershell interprets the pipeline operator so that the subsequent commandlet acts on *each element* in the Arraylist.  Given the context, that line is equivalent to the following:

```
foreach($item in $q){
    Process-xMsmqQueue -queue $item -obj $first
}
```

And, because `$q` contains only a single object, the body of the `foreach` is executed only once.

**Named Parameter**

Now that we know that `$q` is actually an Arraylist of `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` objects, it is no surprise that the following line yields an error:

```
Process-xMsmqQueue -queue $q -obj $second
```

`-queue` accepts `System.Messaging.MessageQueue` but `$q` is of type Arraylist.

---

**Side Note:** The thing that led me astray is that `$q | gm` outputs `TypeName: System.Messaging.MessageQueue`.  However, `$q.GetType()` returns `ArrayList`.  A look at The Get-Member documentation explains the discrepancy:

> When you pipe a collection of objects to Get-Member, Get-Member gets
>   the members of the individual objects in the collection, such as the
>   properties of each string in an array of strings.

---

### Question 2

> Why isn't System.String affected by the difference?

It is, if you obtain a string in the same way:

```
New-Object System.String('MyString') -OutVariable $str
```

`$str` is an ArrayList of `System.String` objects.  If I pass it by name to a parameter expecting `System.String`, I get the same `ParameterArgumentTransformationError`.

### Question 3

> How can I change this script to make passing by named parameter work for -queue?

There are a few options:

1. Use `=` to assign the output of `New-Object`: `$q=New-Object ...`  This way `$q` contains a single object not the ArrayList you get with `-OutVariable`
2. Change `Process-xMsmqQueue -queue` to accept `System.Messaging.MessageQueue[]`.  The commandlet would need to iterate over the ArrayList.
3. Index `$q` like this: `Process-xMsmqQueue -queue $q[0]`  This gets the first element of the ArrayList that was produced by `New-Object`

Comment: A pipeline is not equivalent to `foreach($i in $many)`. The pipeline is asynchronous, and each item is passed separately. When you use `foreach($i in $many)` it collects all the results before continuing with the pipeline.

Comment: @Eris can you recommend a good reference for precisely how the pipeline handles execution?  Everything I've found gets into detail about parameter bindings but glosses over its execution strategy.

Comment: Nothing canonical, but the Scripting Guy blog has a some good articles. Here is the one explaining `Foreach-Object` vs `foreach()`: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/07/08/getting-to-know-foreach-and-foreach-object.aspx